# Lining up the model to a .FBX file

Tags: animation, rigging, .fbx

[image]So I have a .FBX file of someone running and I have a simple 3D object and I want to apply the .FBX file to the 3D figure. But the problem is, the start of the .FBX animation is a different pose then the 3D figure. What I'm asking is, how do I get the 3D figure to line up with thwe .FBX file? Thanks!
Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl3OE.jpg).

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and **use the tools from this site to upload images** so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are going to have to repose the object that you are lining it up to. 2.81 Has the new pose move tool in sculpt mode that will make that easy if it is not rigged. However, if you want to pay for something like Auto rig pro, you could have that pose fixed in not much more than a minute the easy way.